# pthread on Code Composer Studio 5

Tags: pthreads, code-composer

I'm new to pthread and CCS.
My question is:
how can I create a project in CCS to compile and run (simulate at first, than put in Shannon board) a pthread application?
Which project to choose when creating it? Which projects settings should be fixed?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a project and go to: "Project" -> "Properties" -> "C/C++ Build" -> "Setings"

You will find a tab called "Tool Setting", then go to "Cross GCC Linker" -> "Libraries", and  in the secction "Libraries (-l)" click on new and add "lpthead".

Its done. Build your project and see if the errors will occur.

Comment: There is no need to include signatures in your posts.  That is what you user card (below each of your posts) is for =)  See the [faq#signatures] section on signatures.